# Uri's to Skype: are not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, skype

We use a lot links in HTML pages to link and start a video conversation via Skype. A typical button looks like:

```
<a href="skype:someuser?call&amp;video=true">Bellen</a>
```

This works great in Firefox, FireFox(on Android), the native Android browser and IE. Though, in Chrome it doesn't.

What does happen? A GET request is made to the given URI and get the status `(canceled)`

Any ideas on why it is canceled and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The basic design pattern for adding Skype URIs to your webpages involves:

1)Importing the skype-uri.js file from http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/ into your webpage.

2)Using a div tag to mark where you want place the Skype URI on your webpage.

3)Invoking the generator function, Skype.ui, to create and append an anchor element, based on a JSON representation of the Skype object, and append it to your webpage.

You can find the full reference here:
http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-webpages#uriTutorialWebpages

Comment: As you can see in the page you refer to the first option is to use Skype buttons where the link is implemented in the same manner is in my example.